# Augment a complex data type in a generic way in Haskell

Tags: haskell, generics, data-structures, types, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been using the abstract syntax tree (AST) of [Language.C library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c-0.4.7) to modify C programs using generic transformations of [SYB library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb). This AST has different kind of nodes (data types), each one representing a C construction, i.e. expressions, statements, definitions, etc. I need now to augment somehow the information that statements carry, i.e. annotate them. I have supposed (maybe I'm wrong) that I cannot modify or redefine the original data type, so I would like to have something like this:

```
annotateAST anns =
   everywhere (mkT (annotateAST_ anns))

annotateAST_ astnode anns 
  | isStmt astnode = AnnStmt astnode (getAnn astnode anns)
  | otherwise = astnode
```

In this way I would have a new ast with annotated statements instead of the original one. Of course, GHC is going to complain because `everywhere`should return the same type that it gets, and this is not what it is happening here.

Concluding, I need to generically annotate an AST without modifying the original data types, and in a way that it is easy to return to the original data structure. 
I have been thinking in different solutions for this problem, but not convinced of any of them, so I decided to share it here.

P.S. I was told that SYB library is not very efficient. Taking into account that the AST of Language.C only derives Data, do I have a more efficient alternative to do generic traversal and modification of the AST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert of that library, but it seems to be designed so to allow user-defined decorations.

This is because all the main data types are parametrized over `NodeInfo`, the standard annotation (only carrying location and name information). E.g. the library provides

```
type CTranslUnit = CTranslationUnit NodeInfo
```

which allows you to define

```
type MyTransUnit = CTranslationUnit MyNodeInfo
data MyNodeInfo = MNI NodeInfo AdditionalStuffHere
```

so to decorate the AST as you wish.

The library provides `Functor` instances that can affect such decorations, as well as an `Annotated` typeclass to retrieve the (possibly user-defined) annotation from any AST node.

I'd try to pursue that approach.

---

The design looks nice. The only drawback I can see is that the annotation type must be the same for all kinds on nodes, which basically forces one to define it as a huge sum of all kinds of annotations one might possibly have inside. For example:

```
-- AST library for a simple lambda-calculus
data AST n
    = Fun n String (AST n)
    | Var n String
    | App n (AST n) (AST n)

-- user code
data Annotation
    = AnnVar ... | AnnFun ... | AnnApp ...
type AnnotatedAST = AST Annotation
```

and we offer no static guarantees on functions being decorated with `AnnFun`, only.

One could wish for a more advanced library design exploiting GADTs such as:

```
-- AST library for a simple lambda-calculus
data Tag = TagFun | TagVar | TagApp
data AST (n :: Tag -> *)
    = Fun (n 'TagFun) String (AST n)
    | Var (n 'TagVar) String
    | App (n 'TagApp) (AST n) (AST n)

-- user code
data Annotation (n :: Tag) where
   AnnFun :: String -> Annotation 'TagFun
   AnnVar :: Int    -> Annotation 'TagVar
   AnnApp :: Bool   -> Annotation 'TagApp
type AnnotatedAST = AST Annotation
```

which guarantees a correct annotation in every node. `AST` would no longer be a `Functor`, but a `Functor`-like class could be defined, at least.

Still -- I'd be grateful that at least the library allows some form of user-defined annotations.

Comment: Thanks @chi! I knew that the AST of the Language.C library was prepared for user annotations. Although all node types shared the same kind of annotations, it would not be a problem for me, but, as you propose, can be a good improvement. Using the provided functionality, what I would need is a way to go from the AST built by the parser (its type is `CTranslationUnit NodeInfo`) to the user-annotated AST (`CTranslationUnit AnnotatedNodeInfo`). Therefore, I will need to use a function similar to `annotateAST` in the question, but, of course,  fulfilling types constraints.

Comment: @SalvadorTamarit You can use `fmap fromNodeInfoToAnnotatedNodeInfo` to perform that, albeit the new annotation in this way can not depend on anything else but the old annotation. If there's a sensible "default" for the new annotation, that might be enough to define your `fromNodeInfo...`. After this transformation, you can use SYB to affect the new annotations so to make them depend on the actual data. (Maybe there's a better approach, but that's all I can see)

Comment: Thank again @chi. Your proposal works. `fmap` can do a nice job here. Thanks for your help.